# Removing the primary key in class based views ( django rest framework )

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

### Problem :

Currently in my api/urls.py I have this line

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserProfileView.as_view()),
```

but I want to get the profile based on `request.user` and so I have the code in **class UserProfileView** as the following :

```
class UserProfileView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    pagination_class = LimitTenPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        except:
            raise APIException('No profile linked with this user')
        return queryset
```

But If I remove the `pk` field from **urls.py** file, I get an error like this :

> AssertionError at /api/profile/
>
> Expected view UserProfileView to be called with a URL keyword argument
>   named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on
>   the view correctly.

Which is expected.

### Possible solution :

I made a **function based view** like this :

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT'])
def user_detail(request):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
    """
    try:
        user_profile_data = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except:
        raise APIException('No profile linked with this user')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user_profile_data)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user_profile_data, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And in the **urls.py** file added this line :

```
url(r'^me/$', views.user_detail),
```

This gets the work done, but I want a **class based solution**, so that in case I needed to use **pagination_class**, **permission_class** and other features of **drf**, I can easily use it.

As of now, since I need to fetch only one object, so **pagination** is out of question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `get_object` that you need to override for a detail-based view rather than `get_queryset`.